# SharePoint 2013 Access is denied. Verify that either the Default Content Access Account has access to this repository

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I'm experiencing the following error while trying to crawl a share:

> Access is denied. Verify that either the Default Content Access Account has access to this repository

The default account has full control on the share, I also tried to manually mount the share with the crawl account and it is working.

Furthermore, looking into the ULS log I found an error on the function `getnamedsecurityinfo` **error 5**.

I can't figure out which is the problem the permissions look fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be fixed by

1. Adding a crawl rule to crawl the file share
2. Specify the same crawl account
3. Check "Do not allow Basic Authentication"

Also make sure Loop back is disabled

```
New-ItemProperty HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa -Name "DisableLoopbackCheck" -Value "1" -PropertyType dword
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. I already tried adding a rule and I can't find the registry key you are referring

Comment: The exact error is: "CFileAccessor::Init GetNamedSecurityInfo returned 5

Comment: The registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa` if doesnt exist you should create it in the WFE.

Comment: I guess that the problem is on the server containing the share. I have 20 content sources and just one is giving me such a problem.

Comment: For example I created another share on the server and I'm getting another error: The crawl account did not have ufficient privileges to access the security attributes of this file or folder. Ensure the crawl account has the 'Manage auditing and security log' privilege
The permission are right I'm sure the crawling user has read and execute in permission and read in sharing tab

Comment: I added the registry key you suggested same error. Do you have any suggestion on how further investigate the error? I'm running out of idea.

Comment: The problem was related to the group policy. The account needs a special permission not listed in the Microsoft requirements.